# Como colocar Collapsible List Group no ajax?

Tags: php, html, ajax, intel-xdk

Estou querendo colocar abas para quando a pessoa tocar na categoria abrir uma lista de produtos, mas não estou conseguindo[![

```js
$(document).on("click","btnMesa1",function(evt)
{
 $.ajax({
  type:"get",
  url:"http://localhost:8080/ProjetoXDK/appModelo/www/php/funcao.php",
  data:"acao=listarprodutos",
  dataType:"json",
  sucess: function(data){
   var $itemlista = "";
   $.each(data.registro,function(i,dados){
    $itemlista += "<input type='checkbox' name='escolhe' class='check' onchange='showQtd(nome,this)' value='' "+dados.codigo+"<label>"+dados.nome+"</label><br>"
                + "<label>"+dados.preco+"</label>"});
   $("lstRelacaoProdutos").html($itemlista);
  },
  error: function(erro,exception){
   navigator.notification.alert(erro.responseText);
  }
 });
 activate_subpage("#produtos");
});
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwcv8.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwcv8.png)